# Difference between accessing Memory Mapped Registers using char and int

Tags: c, embedded

I have been reading about accessing Memory Mapped Registers of peripheral devices and it seems you can do multiple ways. For example:

Method 1:

```
#define MyReg 0x30610000

volatile int *ptrMyReg;
ptrMyReg = (volatile int *) MyReg;
*ptrMyReg = 0x7FFFFFFF; /* Turn  ON all bits */
```

Method 2:

```
#define MyReg 0x30610000

volatile unsigned char *ptrMyReg;
ptrMyReg = (volatile unsigned char *) MyReg;
*ptrMyReg = 0x7FFFFFFF; /* Turn  ON all bits */
```

Question: Is there any specific reason as to why one would choose one over another?

Assume: Size of int on architecture is 4 bytes.

Comment: The reason to choose the first over the second is that the first one will compile, the second won't (because you're trying to assign an `int *` to a `char *`).

Comment: @Praetorian - That was a typo. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*ptrMyReg = 0x7FFFFFFF;`

In the second case, `*ptrMyReg` is of type `unsigned char` so `0x7FFFFFFF` will be converted to `unsigned char` (i.e., value after conversion will be `0xFF`) before assignment and only one byte will be written. I don't think this what you want if you originally intended to write 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the second example isn't valid code, since your typecast doesn't match.  If you fix that to be:

```
ptrMyReg = (volatile unsigned char *)MyReg;
```

Then, yes, they're different.  In the second case, that constant gets truncated, and you will write only `0xFF` to either the most- or least-significant byte of the word at `0x30610000`, depending on endianness.  Regardless, it's the single byte at `0x30610000` that will be written to, and not others.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU architecture may require that all accesses to perihperal registers are e.g. 32 bits wide. If so, doing byte access may cause CPU exception or silent erroneous execution. This is the case on many ARM SoCs.

Answer (score 0):

In method 2, you aren't going to access the entire `int` by dereferencing a pointer to `char` (unless, of course, `sizeof(int)`=1 on your platform).

Other than that, you should look at your hardware. It may behave differently when accessed using memory operands of different sizes.